# My Join Returns Data In Strange Format with Cakephp

Tags: arrays, cakephp, join

I'm trying to find a User's grocery items in a categorized list. The associations are Category hasMany Item hasMany User through Grocery. I'm using the Joins option for find() and am getting correct information in my Array, however I need it displayed differently.

My Controller Action:

```
 function showlist() {
    $this->Category->recursive = -1;
    $options['joins'] = array(
        array('table' => 'items',
            'alias' => 'Item',
            'type' => 'left',
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'conditions' => array(
                'Item.category_id = Category.id'
            )
        ),
        array('table' => 'items_users',
            'alias' => 'Grocery',
            'type' => 'left',
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'conditions' => array(
                'Grocery.item_id = Item.id'
            )
        )
    );
    $options['conditions'] = array(
        'Grocery.user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')
    );
    $options['fields'] = array(
        'Category.*', 'Item.*', 'Grocery.*'
    );

    $categories = $this->Category->find('all', $options);

    $this->set('categories', $categories);
}
```

This works but now it only displays flatly. I need it to show all items of one category in a nested array.

It's showing:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Category] => Array **<--This could be the same category as**
            (...)

        [Item] => Array
            (...)

        [Grocery] => Array
            (...)
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [Category] => Array **<--This**
            (...)

        [Item] => Array
            (...)

        [Grocery] => Array
            (...)
    )
[2]...
```

And I need it to be:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Category] => Array 
            (...
            [Item] => Array
            (...)

            [Item] => Array
            (...)
            )
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [Category] => Array
            (...)

        [Item] => Array
            (...)
    )
[2]...
```

Don't even really need the Grocery array, just have to search thru them for criteria.

---

**New Code**

Controller:

```
function showlist() {
    $this->Category->recursive = -1;
    $options['joins'] = array(
        array('table' => 'items',
            'alias' => 'Item',
            'type' => 'left',
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'conditions' => array(
                'Item.category_id = Category.id'
            )
        ),
        array('table' => 'items_users',
            'alias' => 'Grocery',
            'type' => 'left',
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'conditions' => array(
                'Grocery.item_id = Item.id'
            )
        )
    );
    $options['conditions'] = array(
        'Grocery.user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')
    );
    $options['fields'] = array(
        'Category.*', 'Item.*'
    );
    $options['contain'] = array(
            'Item' 
        );

    $categories = $this->Category->find('all', $options);

    $this->set('categories', $categories);
}
```

Resulting array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [Category] => Array
            (
                [id] => 31
                [parent_id] => 
                [name] => Cereal
                [lft] => 21
                [rght] => 22
            )

        [Item] => Array
            (
                [id] => 23
                [name] => Granola Bars
                [category_id] => 31
                [description] => 
                [user_id] => 
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 23
                        [name] => Granola Bars
                        [category_id] => 31
                        [description] => 
                        [user_id] => 
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 44
                        [name] => Fiber Bars
                        [category_id] => 31
                        [description] => 
                        [user_id] => 
                    )

            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Category] => Array
            (
                [id] => 15
                [parent_id] => 27
                [name] => Household
                [lft] => 31
                [rght] => 32
            )

        [Item] => Array
            (
                [id] => 24
                [name] => Cleaning Cloths
                [category_id] => 15
                [description] => 
                [user_id] => 
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 24
                        [name] => Cleaning Cloths
                        [category_id] => 15
                        [description] => 
                        [user_id] => 
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 25
                        [name] => Air Freshener
                        [category_id] => 15
                        [description] => 
                        [user_id] => 
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 28
                        [name] => Paper Towels
                        [category_id] => 15
                        [description] => 
                        [user_id] => 
                    )

            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Category] => Array
            (
                [id] => 15
                [parent_id] => 27
                [name] => Household
                [lft] => 31
                [rght] => 32
            )

        [Item] => Array
            (
                [id] => 25
                [name] => Air Freshener
                [category_id] => 15
                [description] => 
                [user_id] => 
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 24
                        [name] => Cleaning Cloths
                        [category_id] => 15
                        [description] => 
                        [user_id] => 
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 25
                        [name] => Air Freshener
                        [category_id] => 15
                        [description] => 
                        [user_id] => 
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 28
                        [name] => Paper Towels
                        [category_id] => 15
                        [description] => 
                        [user_id] => 
                    )

            )

    )

[3] => Array
```

Notice how it is including the Items again under the items directly under category. The item that shows directly under category is what I wanted, it is included in the Grocery list. The find() is now returning all of the items within the top category in an Array under the item I was looking for.

Another issue is cake is not grouping items of the same category. So if Air Freshener and Paper Towels were on the same Grocery list, they would not show up in the same category, the category would be listed twice.

Answer (score 0):

***edit***

I just read your other question, would have been better to include that in this post. 
So you want to limit the results of the Categories to the results of the found Grocery model?

I suggest you try to start from the lowest Model (I have done this in my app aswell):

```
$categories = $this->Grocery->Item->Category->find('all', $options);
```

---

Why are you not using Containable? This seems like the perfect situation to use it in.

Add the following to your models:

```
public $actsAs = array('Containable');
```

then retrieve your data like so:

```
$this->Category->find('all', array('contain' => array('Item' => array('contain' =>    array('Grocery'=> array('conditions' => array('Grocery.user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id'))))))));
```

Comment: I've tried both options. I need a top down category approach so it groups grocery items into categories. Grocery is a hasMany through model. Containable doesn't let me weed out Grocery items not on the list. I'm getting he right information now, I just need to change the format of the array.

Comment: @Chris I did exactly what you want in my app. I aggregated my results  and grouped them by the higher model in the tree. The array returned is in a tree like structure and every entity has it's own unique entry. The key to getting it formatted like that is my edited response. Start from the lowest model.

Comment: I gave this a shot and it doesn't limit the table at all. It is returning every Category, regardless of whether it has any items or grocery items

Comment: What I ment was do the same as you did now, so write your joins etc. But use the find starting from the lowest model. It will aggregate your results. Try changing your join from left to inner aswell.

Comment: Now it is doing something queer. It appears to have limited the returned Items to only items  on the Grocery list. It is still now grouping items into categories. But the strangest thing is it is putting other items that are in the same category in an array underneath the [Item] information.

Comment: Can you post your code and result please? I dont quite understand. Are you sure that this is not due to other relationships and recursive find? The limitation of items on the Grocery list is because of the INNER join. I thought that is what you wanted? If you dont want to limit it only use INNER join to join Categories and Items and use left join for the Grocery.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27339/discussion-between-bart-van-remortele-and-chris)